# Verb nominalization with plain form vs の

Tags: grammar, verbs, particle-の, nouns

I was wondering if there is any clear rule as when to use plain form vs の

eg.
その食べっている人。
ラメンをたべるのが好き。

Answer (score 3):

They are grammatically different. ご飯を食べている人 is "person who is having a meal". This phrase ご飯を食べている modifies 人.

Nominalization with の is used for nominalizing a phrase or sentence. This phrase ラーメンをたべる is nominalized by using の such as ラーメンをたべるの.

For example, ラーメンを食べる人が好き(I like the person who eats ramen), ラーメンを食べるのが好き(I like eating ramen).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way to put it. I'll make note.